# How can I specify path of a .dll if I don't know where it will be?

Tags: c++

I am making a program that injects a .dll into a running process. I need to specify the path of the .dll in order for it to inject properly, but if the injector (and .dll) is shared with others how can I specify the direct path? I have thought about having the .exe injector and .dll in the same folder, but I am unsure how to specify that the injector program needs to search to see if the specific .dll is in the same folder as it is. I'll show an example code below:

```
system("start SnippingTool.exe");

    const char* dllPath = "C:\\Users";
    const char* procName = "SnippingTool.exe";
    DWORD procId = 0;

    while (!procId)
    {
        procId = GetProcId(procName);
        Sleep(30);
    }

    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, procId);

    if (hProc && hProc != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        void* loc = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, 0, MAX_PATH, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

        WriteProcessMemory(hProc, loc, dllPath, strlen(dllPath) + 1, 0);

        HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProc, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibraryA, loc, 0, 0);

        if (hThread)
        {
            CloseHandle(hThread);
        }
    }

    if (hProc)
    {
        CloseHandle(hProc);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And I know that I used system to open the process, but I was having the same issue where I did not know how to specify the certain file path that SnippingTool would be on. This may be a simple solution to some, but I am about a week into my journey of learning how to code. Any tips or pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: `GetModuleFileName(NULL, ...)` allows you to retrieve the full path to the calling EXE file. From there it's a simple string manipulation to construct the full path to any file in the same directory.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik or to any file whose location is relative to that directory, not just in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Nice Injector Source Code, looks familiar :P

If you're shipping an injector, ship the DLL in the same folder.

Here's 2 ways you can do it:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

char szExePath[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileNameA(GetModuleHandle(NULL), szExePath, MAX_PATH);
fs::path exePath(szExePath);

fs::path dllPath = exePath.replace_filename("DllName.dll")

if (fs::exists(dllPath))
    std::cout << "File Exists";
else
    std::cout << "File Does Not Exist";
```

```
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    fs::path thisExe = fs::path(argv[0]);
    fs::path currentFolder = dstFolder.remove_filename();
    fs::path dllPath = currentFolder / "DllName.dll"); 
    
    if (fs::exists(dllPath))
        std::cout << "File Exists";
    else
        std::cout << "File Does Not Exist";
}
```